# Grunt uglify - how destination file can have same name as src file with multiple "."

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am new to MEAN & Grunt.
I used ***"ng build --prod --aot"*** for production of my MEAN stack app and now i have these files in my

***dist***
  folder

1. inline.2b13c4abf73bfbc8e0d1.bundle.js
2. main.907b8423747dc933c849.bundle.js
3. polyfills.477545a8be21bde7f43e.bundle.js
4. vendor.61844e8ff3b3b4fa4491.bundle.js

I am trying to minify these files as these can still be reduced and 30kb size can be saved .

I used grunt with these src and dest :

```
uglify: {
         files: {
                src: 'dist/*.js',
                dest: 'dist/',
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                ext: '.js'
            }
```

}

On "grunt uglify" command I get the files

1. inline.js
2. main.js
3. polyfills.js
4. vendor.js

How can I get the same file name that angular build provided me ?
And please provide options that can maximize reduction in size(optional) 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding extDot worked for me ,

```
files: {
                src: 'dist/*.js',
                dest: 'dist/',
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                ext: '.js',
                extDot: 'last'
            }
```